# Which Visual Studio update should I download for Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, version

I'm using VS Code and it keeps reminding me to update, but I don't know which update version for Linux I should download. I'm still relatively new to all this.

I've attached pictures with information of my current VS version and also the options VS gives me on the web. I hope that's enough to answer my question. I don't know what the differences are between '.deb', '.rpm', 'stable' and 'insiders' hence my doubt.

Thanks in advance.

[My VS version info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrqAj.png) --
[Options presented to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcDGY.png)

Comment: Maybe this https://youtu.be/nfnwhcc1SUg can provide a general perspective

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the installation method and your linux.

- My first advice is to use the package manager of your linux distro if you installed VS Code this way.
- Ubuntu/Debian => .deb file
- Fedora/Red Hat/etc. => .rpm file

It would be helpful to provide more information about your system and/or installation method.

Comment: Hi Tobias. After recieving your comment I have posted any answer. I seemed to have solved the problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After Tobias' comment, I went in search of which Linux system I have and discoverd I have a Debian system.

[Linux System Information (command: cat /etc/os-release)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZFiP.png)

Using that I downloaded Linux x64: Stable: .deb. After downloading this I checked the information about my Visual Studio code and it seems to have updated.

[Visual Studio Code Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N4j0.png)

Thanks @Tobias for your help.